# Changing td element text using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am writing code for HTML file that will display the number of each sum of dice for 36000 thrown dice. I wrote the code, and everything seems fine, I printed the numbers of each sum and I got numbers, but when I try to put them inside the `<td>` element, I see nothing in the table. I searched on Stack Overflow and on google and they all said the same thing, but it's not working. Here is my code:

```css
/*  
        Position #0 : Sum of Dices = 2
        Position #1 : Sum of Dices = 3
        Position #2 : Sum of Dices = 4
        Position #3 : Sum of Dices = 5
        Position #4 : Sum of Dices = 6
        Position #5 : Sum of Dices = 7
        Position #6 : Sum of Dices = 8
        Position #7 : Sum of Dices = 9
        Position #8 : Sum of Dices = 10
        Position #9 : Sum of Dices = 11
        Position #10: Sum of Dices = 12
*/

var sums = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
for (var i = 0; i < 36000; i++) {
  var dice1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  var dice2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  var sum = dice1 + dice2;
  switch (sum) {
    case 2:
      sums[0]++;
      break;
    case 3:
      sums[1]++;
      break;
    case 4:
      sums[2]++;
      break;
    case 5:
      sums[3]++;
      break;
    case 6:
      sums[4]++;
      break;
    case 7:
      sums[5]++;
      break;
    case 8:
      sums[6]++;
      break;
    case 9:
      sums[7]++;
      break;
    case 10:
      sums[8]++;
      break;
    case 11:
      sums[9]++;
      break;
    case 12:
      sums[10]++;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

document.getElementById("sum2").innerHTML = sums[0];
document.getElementById("sum3").innerHTML = sums[1];
document.getElementById("sum4").innerHTML = sums[2];
document.getElementById("sum5").innerHTML = sums[3];
document.getElementById("sum6").innerHTML = sums[4];
document.getElementById("sum7").innerHTML = sums[5];
document.getElementById("sum8").innerHTML = sums[6];
document.getElementById("sum9").innerHTML = sums[7];
document.getElementById("sum10").innerHTML = sums[8];
document.getElementById("sum11").innerHTML = sums[9];
document.getElementById("sum12").innerHTML = sums[10];
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h1>Roll Dice 36,000 Times</h1>
  <table border="1">
    <th>Sum of Dice</th>
    <th>Total Times Rolled</th>

    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td id="sum2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td id="sum3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td id="sum4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td id="sum5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td id="sum6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td id="sum7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td id="sum8"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td id="sum9"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td id="sum10"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td id="sum11"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td id="sum12"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Some said to use `.innerText`, and `.textContent` but none seemed to work. Why is it not working?

Comment: first thing : your switch simplifies to : `sums[sum-2]++`. That will help readability.

Comment: Put your script tag after the elements you are tring to modify (like just be fore the closing </html>), the DOM elements you are tring to modify have not rendered yet, or wrap it up in a onload function

Comment: Its working here: http://jsfiddle.net/64j5h/

Comment: i think it is executing before td's are loaded completely.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use windows.onload function to be sure html is loaded:

```
window.onload=function(){

        document.getElementById("sum2").innerHTML = sums[0];
        document.getElementById("sum3").innerHTML = sums[1];
        document.getElementById("sum4").innerHTML = sums[2];
        document.getElementById("sum5").innerHTML = sums[3];
        document.getElementById("sum6").innerHTML = sums[4];
        document.getElementById("sum7").innerHTML = sums[5];
        document.getElementById("sum8").innerHTML = sums[6];
        document.getElementById("sum9").innerHTML = sums[7];
        document.getElementById("sum10").innerHTML = sums[8];
        document.getElementById("sum11").innerHTML = sums[9];
        document.getElementById("sum12").innerHTML = sums[10];
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Your JS runs before the DOM was ready. Put your script within `window.onload` and try again,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
       window.onload = function(){

                /*

                    Position #0 : Sum of Dices = 2
                    Position #1 : Sum of Dices = 3
                    Position #2 : Sum of Dices = 4
                    Position #3 : Sum of Dices = 5
                    Position #4 : Sum of Dices = 6
                    Position #5 : Sum of Dices = 7
                    Position #6 : Sum of Dices = 8
                    Position #7 : Sum of Dices = 9
                    Position #8 : Sum of Dices = 10
                    Position #9 : Sum of Dices = 11
                    Position #10: Sum of Dices = 12

                */
                var sums = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

                for (var i = 0; i < 36000; i++) {
                    var dice1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                    var dice2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                    var sum = dice1 + dice2;

                    switch(sum) {
                        case 2:
                            sums[0]++;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            sums[1]++;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            sums[2]++;
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            sums[3]++;
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            sums[4]++;
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            sums[5]++;
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            sums[6]++;
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            sums[7]++;
                            break;
                        case 10:
                            sums[8]++;
                            break;
                        case 11:
                            sums[9]++;
                            break;
                        case 12:
                            sums[10]++;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }

                document.getElementById("sum2").innerHTML = sums[0];
                document.getElementById("sum3").innerHTML = sums[1];
                document.getElementById("sum4").innerHTML = sums[2];
                document.getElementById("sum5").innerHTML = sums[3];
                document.getElementById("sum6").innerHTML = sums[4];
                document.getElementById("sum7").innerHTML = sums[5];
                document.getElementById("sum8").innerHTML = sums[6];
                document.getElementById("sum9").innerHTML = sums[7];
                document.getElementById("sum10").innerHTML = sums[8];
                document.getElementById("sum11").innerHTML = sums[9];
                document.getElementById("sum12").innerHTML = sums[10];

      }
   // -->
   </script>
```

Comment: sorry, mybad it's a typo. it's `onload` only.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    var sums = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

            for (var i = 0; i < 36000; i++) {
                var dice1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                var dice2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                var sum = dice1 + dice2;

                switch(sum) {
                    case 2:
                        sums[0]++;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        sums[1]++;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        sums[2]++;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        sums[3]++;
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        sums[4]++;
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        sums[5]++;
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        sums[6]++;
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        sums[7]++;
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        sums[8]++;
                        break;
                    case 11:
                        sums[9]++;
                        break;
                    case 12:
                        sums[10]++;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            document.getElementById("sum2").innerHTML = sums[0];
            document.getElementById("sum3").innerHTML = sums[1];
            document.getElementById("sum4").innerHTML = sums[2];
            document.getElementById("sum5").innerHTML = sums[3];
            document.getElementById("sum6").innerHTML = sums[4];
            document.getElementById("sum7").innerHTML = sums[5];
            document.getElementById("sum8").innerHTML = sums[6];
            document.getElementById("sum9").innerHTML = sums[7];
            document.getElementById("sum10").innerHTML = sums[8];
            document.getElementById("sum11").innerHTML = sums[9];
            document.getElementById("sum12").innerHTML = sums[10];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
for(var i = 0; i <sums.length; i++){
    document.getElementById("sum" + (i + 2)).innerHTML = sums[i];
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QkyNC/1/)