# innerHTML function not changing the content of my td

Tags: javascript, html, razor

I have an ajax fonction that almost work, the part that doesn't is when it gets to innerHTML function. I'm trying to change the text inside a td when success part is reahced.

In my .cshtml file of an MVC project, I have this simple HTML an JS :

```
// This td is not part of a loop, it is just inside a single table and tr

<td id="SommePour" style="min-width: 480px;" colspan="2">
        Somme pour @(Model.PbSelected?.Insert(4,"-").Insert(3,"-") ?? "000-0-00000")
</td>


<script>
    function NouveauTotal(noCompt9) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ChangeSousTotaux", "Explorer")',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                postBudg9: noCompt9
            },
            success: function (result) {

                $("#SommePour").innerHTML = "<span>Somme pour " + '' + noCompt9 + ''.substring(0, 3) + "-" + '' + noCompt9 + ''.substring(3, 4) + "-" + '' + noCompt9 + ''.substring(4, 9) + "</span>";
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I even tried :

```
$("#SommePour").innerHTML = 'yo';
```

I searched :

[Changing td element text using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473391/changing-td-element-text-using-javascript)

[.substring error: "is not a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164550/substring-error-is-not-a-function)

But nothing came to my mind...

Comment: You're mixing a jQuery object and a DOM property. It should be `$("#SommePour").html(...)`

Comment: Once we're there @Barmar, am I allowed to use substring() or this is going to be the same ?

Comment: Of course you can. A string is the same no matter how you get it.

Comment: Why are you calling `.substring()` on empty strings, though?

Comment: What are you expecting `''.substring(0, 3)` to return?

Comment: Maybe you meant `noCompt9.substring(0, 3)`?

Comment: Yes but it says substring is not a function

Comment: Like my noCmpt9 was not a string or i'm mistaking something else

Comment: How do you call `NouveuTotal()`? Maybe `noCompt9` is a number, not a string.

Comment: Try `noCompt9.toString().substring(0, 3)`

Comment: Ha ! Yes .toString with a small "t" ... annoying reactive code JQuery and JS. It's always the complicated part for me. You have the right answer now

Comment: It's kind of strange to take substrings of a number, since it depends on how big the number is. Do all your numbers have the same number of digits?

Comment: It is a string, and yes, it is just like a phone number, always same amount of digits. Sadly, since it is composed of only numbers, it seems like when I call my function : `<tr onclick="NouveauTotal(@item.NoCompt.Substring(0,9))">` the browser decide it's an int suddently. Why ? Good question

Comment: I think it's Razor doing that, not the browser.

Comment: Ha, yeah those Razor pages on asp.net are sometimes doing extra stuff, sometimes good extra stuff... sometimes... this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using jQuery, the correct syntax is

```
$("#SommePour").html("What you want to add");
```

It's supposed to be .html

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_html.asp

Comment: `html` is a function, you have to call it.

Comment: That's true, my mistake, I'll correct the answer.